# Typescript y ES6 import

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, javascript-import

Estoy tratando de transpilar un archivo con extensión .ts a ES6 pero no me funciona y fuera de eso ni me arroja algún error typescript.

El problema se da cuando utilizo el import de ES6 y no require.

Nota:tengo actualizado node.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: que tool usas para convertir el ts a js? usas por ejemplo Visual Studio Code. que pasa si conviertes a ES5, lo hace correctamente?

Comment: Buenas noches,no sucede nada yo tengo este tsconfig y si uso vscode:         {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./public/js",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}

Comment: @oscarleandrovierapereira con un ejemplo básico pudiste compilar alguna vez??

Answer (score 1):

Debes definir correctamente el archivo tsconfig.json, adjunto el que utilizo en este momento para convertir de TS 2.1 a JS.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Ejemplo de importación de modulos npm en un controlador TS.

```
'use strict'

import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { PaginateModel, Schema, model } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
```

Answer (score 0):

Analizando

[Editing TypeScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript)

puedo ver algunos puntos

- intenta definiendo un tsconfig mas basico, quita por ejempo el `outDir`
- valida que tengas el `tasks.json`
- intenta generando la compilacion usando `Ctrl+Shift+B`

Cuando dices que no sucede nada validad la carpeta que defines en el `outDir` quizas alli es donde deja el .js generado

Comment: Buenas noches nuevamente,Sí genera un archivo pero en blanco,el problema parece ser el import de ES6 ya que con el require no sucede,sin embargo tengo actualizado node y tengo los typings del core instalados.

Comment: si lo genera en blanco es porque no esta compilando, debes tener algun error en el codigo typescript, mientas no compile el js no se va a generar, ademas en la config que usas no veo que definas en ningun lado ES6, el target que veo esta definido es ES5

Comment: Buenas noches,el problema es que solo no funciona cuando utilizo por ejemplo: import * as fs from "fs", mientras que con require sí,la verdad nadie ha podido darme razón sobre lo que sucede y llevo días y no logro dar con el "error" sí es que hay ya que no me salen errores.